# Calculation of compression ratio using arithmetic encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, compression, entropy

Arithmetic encoding is one of the most famous entropy encoding techniques, and I am using it to encode an image. For this, I am using the built-in function of Matlab that also gives other values such as seq, counts, and source along with the binary code. From theory, compression is done based on the probability distribution of data. The arithmetic encoder encodes the sequence based on its probability. Now the main thing I want to know is about the calculation of the compression ratio. Is the compression ratio only calculated using the code/binary code, or are other parts also included? If yes, can someone please let me know how to calculate the size and other required stuff for me? These data are either present in a high precision manner or have high values.

I am also adding the codes for the arithmetic encoding:

```
function [code,seq,counts,source] = arithmetic_coding(message)

%strfind: finds the string within another string.
source=unique(message);
counts=zeros(1,length(source));
for i=1:length(source)
    counts(i)=length(strfind(message,source(i)));   
end

%counts
seq=zeros(1,length(message));
for i=1:length(message)
    seq(i)=strfind(source,message(i));
end
%seq
code = arithenco(seq, counts);
end
```

The code for arithmetic decoding:

```
function dec_message = arithmetic_decoding(code,counts,seq,source)
dseq = arithdeco(code,counts,length(seq));
dec_message=zeros(1,length(dseq));
for i=1:length(dseq)
    a=dseq(i);
    dec_message(i)=source(a);
end
end
```

Comment: What would be your definition of the compression ratio?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What function are you using? `arithenco()` only returns the resulting binary code. What "other parts" are you talking about?

Comment: @SolarMike I am using (1-(compressed_size/uncompressed_size))*100 as the definition of my compression ratio. Thus higher the percent more the compression achieved.

Comment: @MarkAdler That is right that arithenco() only returns the code but while decoding while decoding using arithdeco() it not only requires the binary code, but the 'counts' as well which are used during the encoding.
Thus this is my point if we need to add this 'counts' i.e. statistics of the symbol, while calculating the compression ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is needed by `arithdeco()` to decode must be transmitted or stored, and so counts as compressed data for the calculation of the compression ratio. So the code, the counts, and the length. The uncompressed data is simply the sequence.

You will need to determine how you will send the counts and length in order to compute their size. The counts should themselves be compressed to minimize the total size of the compressed data.

Comment: To compress the 'counts' should i need to apply another set of compression algorithm ? Like Wouldn't that produce another set of data that is needed by the decoder again.

Comment: Yes, the compressed counts would be used in place of the uncompressed counts.